# Can you use fancy fonts in Google Play app name

Tags: android, google-play, mobile-application

To what degree you can use something other than standard alphanumeric characters as a **valid app name in Google Play**?

Is it possible to name app like this:
`my  app` (Fancy Text)

Or like this:
`my CΩΩL app` (mixed latin-greek or something, there is μTorrent right)

Comment: Try it and see what happens